# "command 'vscode.previewHtml' not found", cannot get preivew of latex

Tags: mac, visual-studio-code

I have this error flashing everytime I try to use VS for Latex. I have no idea how to proceed. One thing I noticed is that it can load pdf that already exists in the folder.

error:

> command 'vscode.previewHtml' not found

using

> Latex Workshop 8.0.5
>
> Latex preview 0.5.1

os

> mac

I am also very new into this, so apologies if this is some stupid question. I tried a  lot of googling, but couldn't understand any solution.

Looking for help. Thank you.

Comment: There is the discussion on the topic: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/527463/pdf-preview-in-visual-studio-code. Should be helpful. :)

Comment: @Mia thank you, I will check the same.